# put in coprocessor postBatchMutate

Tags: hbase, mvcc

I want to put a new key-value for the current row in BaseRegionObserver.postBatchMutate, but I stuck in MVCC and a deadlock is occurring. Here is my code:

```
    @Override
public void postBatchMutate(ObserverContext<RegionCoprocessorEnvironment> c,
                            MiniBatchOperationInProgress<Mutation> miniBatchOp) throws IOException {
    for (int i = 0 ; i < miniBatchOp.size(); i ++) {
        Put put = null;
        Mutation op = miniBatchOp.getOperation(i);
        if (! (op instanceof Put))
            continue;

        put = (Put) miniBatchOp.getOperation(0);

        if (put.has(Bytes.toBytes("m"), Bytes.toBytes("id")))
            return;

        Put put1 = new Put(put.getRow());
        put1.addColumn(Bytes.toBytes("m"), Bytes.toBytes("id"),
            Bytes.toBytes(String.valueOf(UUID.randomUUID())));

        c.getEnvironment().getRegion().put(put1);

    }
}
```

You can find this repeating WARN message in the output:

WARN regionserver.MultiVersionConcurrencyControl: STUCK: MultiVersionConcurrencyControl{readPoint=3, writePoint=5}

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind posting your code?  You can always grab the region from the coprocessor and manually perform a put.  It is not clear to me what your failure semantics are...  Do both have to succeed or fail?

Comment: My problem was on postBatchMutate. It seems that I have no problem with postPut.